# $n!>a$, can we solve for $n$ in terms of $a$?

Tags: factorial

Can we explicitly solve $n$ in terms of $a$? Can we rewrite this inequality in the form of $n>f(a)$ without using $n!$ the factorial?

Comment: Well I guess you could extend factorial to gamma function and restrict the domain to a strictly increasing region so that the gamma function is invertible. Then you have $n>\Gamma^{-1}(a)$